# Why couldn't bitcoin be hosted on the internet?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I was wondering why bitcoin wasn't hosted on the internet? Why create a completely separate decentralized network, I thought the internet was already decentralized. For example, couldn't they have rented a few amazon ec2's or some other servers hosted on xyz host and call it a day?

(Sorry for newb question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, bitcoin is on the internet, and the Internet is not decentralized, its managed by several private companies, universities and governmental institutions.

You said "couldn't they have rented a few amazon ec2's or some other servers hosted on xyz host and call it a day"

I don't know who do you mean by "they" whoever you mean, just replace it by bitcoin users and the answer is Yes, I've rented some servers on Amazon and it's connected to other bitcoin nodes.

Comment: Yeah sure, All bitcoin communications are done over TCP also, IPv6 is supported.

Comment: And onion... and sattelite (not internet) and cantenna (not internet) and ...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Adam. Bitcoin relies on blockchain, without it BTC can't exist. And Blockchain uses the Internet basically. Maybe some day people would create another blockchain technology, which wouldn't require the Internet connection... but that's another story.

Comment: `And Blockchain uses the Internet basically` This is incorrect, you can absolutely run a blockchain on just one computer, or a local network.